# How does Discord hook into a specific process's audio?

Tags: winapi, audio, hook, reverse-engineering

Going through Google search results, there is no widely known way to capture audio from a specific application on Microsoft Windows, at least without having to resort to workarounds such as sending audio from one process to a separate virtual audio loopback device (which however results in an inability to hear the sound, unless you either use a hardware loopback playback device or "listen" to the emulated input via the main output).

These workarounds are clunky, require configuration for each specific application and software will often misbehave, no longer successfully make any sound or straight-up stop working if their output device is changed during execution. Meanwhile, launching a [Discord](https://discord.com) "Live Streaming" session allows you to easily, without failure, share a single application's sound with a VoIP group call. Sound from other application is completely removed. Looking at audio devices, it appears that no virtual loopback routing is taking place, and there is absolutely zero interruption in audio playback on the client side. The functionality isn't available on the macOS or Linux versions of the software, only on Windows. Capturing sound from a specific process is thus possible in Win32, but why isn't anyone else doing this? What would it take, say, to implement something like this in a fork of software where such functionality would be extremely useful, like OBS or Audacity?

Comment: I believe WASAPI [Loopback Recording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording) allows you to still render the captured output. Though I'm not sure how you would set up process-specific capturing. Maybe there's something in the [Core Audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/about-the-windows-core-audio-apis) APIs that address this particular use case.

Comment: @IInspectable WASAPI only supports rendering output from all system devices combined. It happens at hardware level inside the audio interface so it can't be used to capture a process independently. What bothers me is that this is perfectly possible to achieve in a consistently reliable way: Discord did it. But there seems to be no info on this specifically.

Comment: Hi I added a bounty to this question. I would like to know how it is done on macos as well  please

Comment: @drikoda Thanks for adding a bounty on this. I don't think application audio capture is available on macOS though.

Comment: Most of PCs runing windows use Realtek chip which support (hadrware) audio mixing, this interface is present in the driver and you can intercept audio from it, mybe this is what they are doing.

Comment: I think you can screen record in Mac Os using the Quick Player with audio. If you wish to do this programmatically, well I believe swift has a screen recorder class you could explore.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder

Since QuickTime Player has system privilege's to record screen with audio, try this to see if it works for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFnEPJZL-xM

Comment: @ShayRibera I was talking about Discord, which doesn't have, on the Mac, the same capability as on Windows

Comment: It does not have the same capabilities because of the operating system permissions, that is why using QuickTime should work, since it is a built in app, and has the permissions needed.

Comment: @phoenixstudio My machine doesn't have Realtek Audio (no built-in audio drivers are installed) and I use a Focusrite Scarlett 4i4, definitely not an audio interface Discord was meant for. And this feature works regardless. I believe this feature is available on all hardware.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: Not sure if this is useful at all, but I found this page: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/audio-sources.465/

In particular, this strikes me as useful information:

> It's quite similar to hooking Direct3D. You hook the IAudioRenderClient interface, and intercept GetBuffer to read the audio samples.

Beginner's reverse engineering time!

Also, I cannot give a definitive answer, but I can lead you in the right direction.

Discord has a directory called `\modules\discord_hook` inside of it's root directory, here we can find there is a JavaScript file, named `index.js`, a json file named `manifest.json`, a `.node` file, named `discord_hook.node` (which is compiled/encrypted and I cannot read), a directory with `.dll`s and `.exe`s, and it also generates a log file, named `hook.log`.

`index.js` appears to just load `discord_hook.node` and do some other things that aren't important to us.

Googling `manifest.json` brings me here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json

> The `manifest.json` file is the only file that every extension using WebExtension APIs must contain.

In the `.json` file, we find it is referencing the `.exe`s, `.dll`s, `discord_hook.node`, `index.js`, and itself.

The .node file as previously mentioned is for the most part unreadable by a human being.

`hook.log` doesn't output anything seemingly helpful, just stuff about the graphics/video share.

This leaves us with looking inside the `exe` and `dll` files inside the subdirectory here, I have no knowledge of `asm`, but we can look at some strings left inside of these binaries.

I found a section of strings referencing audio at offset 1266B4 to offset 126EA6 in `DiscordHook.dll` (This may and almost definitely WILL change in future versions of discord)

Here are some of the strings that seem to be worth posting here.

```
Audio buffer stopped, WASAPI capture stopping
Failed to get format of WASAPI audio buffer, not capturing, error code [%d]
Failed to get WASAPI audio client from render client, not capturing
Starting capture of WASAPI buffer with sample rate %d, depth %d, %d channels
Starting capture of Windows Sonic stream with downmix sample rate %d, depth %d, %d channels
ISpatialAudioObjectRenderStream::Stop
ISpatialAudioObjectRenderStream::BeginUpdatingAudioObjects
ISpatialAudioObjectRenderStream::EndUpdatingAudioObjects
ISpatialAudioObject::GetBuffer
HookWasapi failed to load audioses.dll
WaveFormatFromRenderClient failed with error code [%d]
LoadWASAPIOffsets failed with error code [%d]
WASAPI module sizes don't match (expected: %lu, actual: %lu)
WASAPI offsets invalid (stop: %lu, getBuffer: %lu, releaseBuffer: %lu, clientOffset: %lu, endpointOffset: %lu)
WASAPI offsets out of bounds (size: %lu, stop: %lu, getBuffer: %lu, releaseBuffer: %lu)
IAudioClient::Stop
IAudioRenderClient::GetBuffer
IAudioRenderClient::ReleaseBuffer
HookWasapi: MH_ApplyQueued failed 0x%x
```

Also, I googled "hook process audio" and found this:
https://ywjheart.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/audio-captureapihook-based-for-obs-studio/

It doesn't give any code examples, or downloads, but it describes some stuff on doing this very thing but in OBS. They also link the stuff they used to document it at the bottom.

Good luck, I hope all this information can help in some way!

Comment: Looks like the .node files are external libraries that are imported in Node.js with [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp).